# When switching between tabs selected recyclerView item stays highlighted

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments and each one of them has a RecyclerView. I highlight selected item in RecyclerView adapter (i need only one selected item at once). But when i switch between fragments, and select an item in another fragment, previous one stays selected. I need previous item to unselect somehow , when i select an item in another fragment.

Here is how i select an item in RecyclerView adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SoundViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(soundList[position]) 
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            test(holder.adapterPosition)
        }
        holder.itemView.isSelected = selectedPosition === position

    }
fun test(position: Int){
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
        selectedPosition = position
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
    }
```